# does innerHTML get rid of elements entirely?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

**EDIT: I figured it out, thanks for your time!**

I have a div with an id of container and three buttons above that.

When a user clicks any of the buttons above, then javascript replaces the contents of the div according to the buttons pressed using innerHTML.

Clicking on each button once works fine because I'm just replacing the elements in the div. But when I try to reclick the buttons my console prints out **'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null '**

So I'm assuming innerHTML gets rid of the elements entirely. Is there a way to retrieve those elements so I can constantly click the buttons and have the respective elements appear?

If not, I was thinking of having a div for each button in my html file and then using display:none. When a user clicks on any of the buttons, the div for that button will be set to display:block.

*****Edit******. **I believed I answered my own question.****

Yes, using innerHTML does get rid of previous elements inside the div container. Therefore, if you wanted to grab those elements again, you can't. and the above error will be printed in the console.

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4vD/

```
 <div id="buttonNav">
   <button id="button1">1</button>
   <button id="button2">2</button>
   <button id="button3">3</button>
</div>
<div id="container">
<p id="para">Data in paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your source code here for us to better understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: I tried to [reproduce the problem you described](http://jsbin.com/tenojalu/1/) but could not. The elements still existed and were accessible when I tried to read them after overwriting them in the DOM with innerHTML. You should provide a reduced test case that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: okay, got it  Working on it. I definitely need to simplify it because I'm extracting data from MySQL through AJAX so I'm working on a JSFiddle right now

Comment: Check console in JSFiddle, you're still getting the error, and I've already written the reason in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried the following, and it worked perfect, check it:-

```
<button type="button" id="red"onclick="myFunction(id)"> Red!</button>
<button type="button" id="blue"onclick="myFunction(id)"> Blue!</button>
<button type="button" id="green"onclick="myFunction(id)"> Green!</button>
<div id="container"></div>

 <script>
 function myFunction(e){
 document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = e
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is that I'm not grabbing data from the HTML page itself, I'm extracting it from a database instead. My fault for not making my answer more clear

Comment: I think in this case grabbing data from server and any other hrml content should not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now got the problem.

You're writing:-

```
<div id="container">
<p id="para">Data in paragraph</p>
 </div>
```

and then,

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
```

and then you're setting the innerHTML with a sring:-

```
container.innerHTML = data;
```

So, suppose data = "abc";

The your html becomes

```
  <div id="container">
  abc
  </div>
```

So, the p tag is not present here.

Thus when you're try the following in the next time:-

```
document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = data2;
```

It's not getting anything and showing the error.

Either you replace

```
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = data2;
```

with

```
   container.innerHTML = data2;
```

And remove the p tag from your html, or write:-

```
 var para= document.getElementById('para');
```

and then write the following in respective cases:-

```
para.innerHTML = data2;
para.innerHTML = data;
```